# Plugin to create unlimited custom shortcodes?

Tags: plugins, multisite, plugin-recommendation

I want to be able to create unlimited shortcodes and use them anywhere on my theme, pages or posts.

The idea is:

A textfield for the shortcode name.
A textarea for the shortcode content (html+js).

I found this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-generator/

But it's really old and outdated, I am using wp 3.2.1 with multisite.

Does someone knows if a plugin like this exists and it's compatible with wp 3.2.1 and the multisite feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

- [Shortcodes Pro](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcodes-pro/)
- [Shortcode Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortbus/)
- [Shortcode Exec PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/)
- [Shortcoder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcoder/)

Comment: The only one of those that seems to do what I need is Shortcode Exec PHP, which allows me to manage the shortcodes from the network admin dashboard and use them on all the sites on the multisite installation. I don't love the GUI of this plugin but it's the only one that does this so I guess I will use this one. Thanks.